# Is there a way to include a SQL/JDBC database in a Java WAR web application so users don't have to set up MySQL?

Tags: java, spring, database, jdbc, war

I have a Java Spring MVC web application.

To run it, users have to install and configure a MySQL database for it to connect to (to load configuration and store user info and so on).

Is there a way to include an SQL database in the WAR file that is ready to use, so users don't have to set up the MySQL database?

Comment: You can use HSQLDB or H2

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks ... I did a Spring Boot tutorial a while back that used an embedded Hypersonic SQL database (don't remember if it was HSQLDB or H2) ... but the guy said it should only be used in dev, not in production.  Is that not correct?

Comment: In general HSQLDB and H2 are not considered "production" but that is a matter of definition.  MySQL may not be production either if it's not setup that way.  But the answer is no, not really.  The .war file may not be writable and so you can't embed a database.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using SQLite by following [this guide available on baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-sqlite).

In-Memory Database like SQLite or HSQLDB or H2 should be used in case you want the data **not** to be persisted.

Comment: This database will be used for storing the configuration data that the application needs to run.  The user specifies external datasources and project configurations and so on.  All of that gets stored in this db.  So it's important that this data is stored/saved properly and is re-read when the web app is restarted.